# Регистронезависимый in в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Каким образом сделать регистронезависимый поиск по массиву?

```
select 'id' from users where lower(username) in ('VaSyA','peTya','Masha')
```

нашел инфу по [citext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311289/postgresql-case-insensitive-select-on-array), но как-то сомневаюсь. не лучше склеить массив и пройтись лайком?

Answer (score 1):

Можешь, например, так:

```
select id from tablename where upper(first_name) = ANY(select upper(unnest(ARRAY['VaSyA','peTya','Masha'])));
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_lower(anyarray, int)`

[Array Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html)

Comment: а это тут при чём?

Comment: Сейчас уже не вспомню. Но на тот момент оно помогло.

Comment: напиши, пожалуйста, пример запроса